# svn stat says folder uncontrolled, but won't let me svn add it!

Tags: svn

Running into a weird problem with svm. I do svn stat in my controlled directory, lists something like:

```
?   myproject/foo
?   myproject/zoo
```

so I do:

```
svn add myproject/zoo
```

and then I get this message back:

```
svn: warning: 'myproject/zoo' is already under version control
```

I don't get it, why is it showing it as uncontrolled then? I tried running svn cleanup, svn update, nothing though.

I am also looking at my svn project in tracker, and I don't see the /zoo folder as present. What can I do to convince svn it's not really added?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is there a .svn subdirectory within `foo` and `zoo`?

As mentioned in [this thread](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=1128):

> - `svn st` from the top folder shows that the folder is unversioned (because the 
>     parent folder does not know about it).
> - `svn add` fails because there is already a `.svn` folder inside of this folder.
>
> Depending what you want to do, this might fix things:

```
$ rm -Rf myproject/foo/.svn
```

That can happen when `foo` is deleted locally (the parent folder record a deletion), but svn wasn't able to remove the `.svn` under `foo` (for some reason like a process keeping an handle on that subdirectory), causing any future `svn add` to fail, thinking it is already under version control.